# PHP 'self' foreach

Tags: php

Let's say I have...

```
abstract class Foo
{
    public static $bar1 ...
    public static $bar2 ...
    public static $bar3 ...

    public static function getBars() {
        // ... //
    }
}
```

I want `getBars()` to return a list of all those static bar variables. So I tried...

```
public static function getBars() {
    foreach(self as $value) {
        echo $value . '<br>';
    }
}
```

No go. Apparently `$this` works with foreach but `self` does not. Any ideas?

EDIT: A little background, I'm trying to mimic Java-like enums, the bars are the different types like "MONDAY, TUESDAY, ..." and `getBars()` is meant to mimic a values iterator.

Comment: This design isn't good. What about a list of bars instead?

Comment: Why not store them in an array?  `public static $bars;`?  Then: `self::$bars = [$bar1, $bar2, $bar3];`

Comment: Ugh, use `ReflectionClass` or `get_class_vars` or `get_object_vars`, whichever best meets your requirements

Comment: You can't very easily loop over `self` (barring reflection mumbo jumbo) for much the same reason that you can't very easily loop over all locals:  because variables weren't intended to act like that.  :P  If you want a `$bar1`, `$bar2`, `$bar3`, etc that you want to loop over....what you *really* want is an array named `$bar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
$staticProperties = $reflectionClass->getStaticProperties();
```

And you will have them in an array.

Comment: this works and reflection is maybe a thing that is not known enough in the PHP world - but for me, reflection more for debugging and analyzing, not so much for production code

Comment: @cypherabe I agree, but it seems from the code that that is how it is used, I cannot imagine that in a live site.

Answer (score 2):

'self' is the current class whereas $this is the current instance.
In order to iterate on something, you need to actually have something. 'self' is the model where $this is the actual object.